# how to hide a class, that is used on several places on the page, *from a specific element only*, with css media query

Tags: css, class, media-queries, responsive

I am using a wrapper at certain places on the page, and on smaller displays, i want to stop using it, but only on one element.

```css
.place {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(340px, 460px) minmax(352px, 484px);
  
  
@media screen and (max-width: 754px) {
  .place {
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 100vw));
   grid-gap: 25px
  }
  
  .place > .narrower {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="places narrower">
  <div class="place">
    <h2 class="place__title">Maine</h2>
    <div class="place__website">
      <h3 class="place__url-heading">url</h3>
```

i tried display none. ofcourse it reacts on all the elements with the narrower class is placed on the html.

so how do i remove it at 754px only from places section.places?

Comment: Do you want to  hide all element with narrower class except some specific elements?

Comment: I can't quite make sense of your CSS as narrower seems to be a class in section, after which is an element with class place, not the other way round,

Comment: i want to just remove the use of narrower from places, at a certain width of screen

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide all elements except some specific elements try to combine your CSS selector with ":not" pseudo-selector.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 754px) {
  .place {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 100vw));
    grid-gap: 25px;
  }

  .place > .narrower:not(section.narrower) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```